# change print preview page size from letter to A4

Tags: windows-7, firefox, printing

Firefox 9, how to switch the print preview size from letter to A4, and change all of the default "letter" paper sizes to "A4"?

Answer (score 1):

Please write what type of operating system you use.

If you use Ubuntu Linux you can change the file `/etc/papersize` from

```
letter
```

to

```
A4
```

by running *Terminal* from the menu and typing `sudo gedit /etc/papersize`

Comment: Can't believe I forgot to add the operating system... it's Windows 7

Comment: I would like to comment that this also works on Arch Linux for Libre Office. Thanks a lot. I did not know that this exists.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this forum post addresses your FF print preview question well:

http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=480477&start=0&st=0&sk=t&sd=a